# Sell a unique product with

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to sell a single product (a CD) on a Drupal 8 site and I'm looking for a simple way to pay.

I guess in this case, it's not worth using the Commerce or Ubercart module.

In fact, I intend to make a page presenting the CD with a button referring to a means of payment and return once the transaction made.

Is this the right solution?
Or maybe there is another way of doing things?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems a full commerce solution is an overkill for a single product.

If you don't need visitors to pay through your site you can use some solutions that take them away to payment processors website to complete the order.

You will have to pull reports and sort out the accounting side of things from the payment processor records, since you won't have orders on your website.

You have to investigate for the ways you "deliver" the product once someone pays for your product, and how that is tracked, maybe again through the payment processor.